# Is it possible to create a pointer to an object of a class that contains overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, oop

I have some questions. I created a class that contains operator overloading:

```
double MMatrix::operator()(int i, int j)const
{
    return A[j + i * nCols];
}
```

To Pass an instance of that class to a function efficiently, I used to create a pointer of that class as the function formal parameter. And I want to use this overloaded operator in such a pointer to the class object within that function:

```
void Set_Matrix(MMatrix* M)
{
    size_t m = M->NRows();
    size_t n = M->NCols();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        M(i, i) = 2; //This line gives error

}
```

The last line in that function gives an error message:
*E0109 expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type*
I would appreciate you if you give me the solution to this problem.

Comment: When I used the reference parameter, i.e (MMatrix & M) instead of a pointer, (MMatrix *M), I found that it works. But I still want to know how to do it?

Comment: `M` is a pointer so you have to use `(*M)(i,i) = 2;`

Comment: Your operator function is declared to work on `const` class references. So that cannot work.

Comment: What are you hoping `= 2;` will do?  You probably want `operator()` to return a reference to the value in the matrix.  Assigning `2` to a temporary return value accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that `M` is a pointer to `MMatrix` so you would first have to dereference that pointer to get the underlying object of type `MMatrix` and then use the overloaded `operator()` as shown below:

```
void Set_Matrix(MMatrix* M)
{
    size_t m = M->NRows();
    size_t n = M->NCols();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; i++)
//------vvvv----------------->dereference M first before using operator()
        (*M)(i, i) = 2;

}
```

Other option is to make the parameter to be of type `MMatrix&` as shown below:

```
//---------------------v---->lvalue reference
void Set_Matrix(MMatrix& M)
{
    size_t m = M.NRows();
    size_t n = M.NCols();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; i++)
//------v----------------->no need of dereferencing
        M(i, i) = 2;

}
```

Note also that the return type of `opeartor()` is `double` and not `double&`, and since we cannot assign to a built in type rvalue the above solutions will generate errors saying the same. To solve that you can make the return type `double&` which will allow us to do the assignment.

Comment: There's also the issue that operator() is const. I think in order to use it for assignment it should be non-const.

Comment: @wohlstad Yes agreed. Also note that OP's current question is only about the error : *"expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type"* which the answer shows how to solve. And so i don't think there is any point in adding more information to the answer as OP didn't provide a minimal reproducible example and it wouldn't help in solving the mentioned error as that was caused by a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner syntax if you pass as a reference

```
void Set_Matrix(MMatrix& M)
{
    size_t m = M.NRows();
    size_t n = M.NCols();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        M(i, i) = 2; <<==

}
```

other siwes you need

```
void Set_Matrix(MMatrix* M)
{
    size_t m = M->NRows();
    size_t n = M->NCols();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        (*M)(i, i) = 2; <<==

}
```

Comment: I don't think it will work as long as operator() is `const`, and returns `double` (instead of `double&`).

Comment: The overloaded form of the operator is just for calling from the right-hand side of the assignment and there is another version in code but without a const identifier. Thank you for all, I got it.